# my deep network doesnt learn anything while training in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

for training a CNN i have a 5(batch_size) inputs of dimensions 16x12x1, and I am using architecture is 
conv1 -> maxpool ->conv2 -> maxpool -> fully connceted -> softmax.
conv1 : 5x5x1 , 16 filters.
conv2 : 5x5x16, 16 filters.
fc    : 16*4*3, 64 hidden nodes.
softmax: 8 outputs

My network doesn't learn any thing. It doesn't show any error either.
cost function is consistent at 2.05xxx
what could be possible reasons ? 
Accuracy of the test is 0.2 or sometimes 0.0.

here is the sample code:

```
layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [5,5,1,16], stddev=0.01))
layer1_biases  = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([16]))

layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [5,5,16,16], stddev=0.01))
layer2_biases  = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([16]))

fc_weights     = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([16*4*3, 64], stddev=0.01))
fc_biases      = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[64]))

Softmax_weights= tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([64, 8], stddev=0.01))
Softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[8]))

def mycnn(x):
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x, layer1_weight, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), layer1_biases))
    layer1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(layer1, layer2_weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), layer2_biases))
    layer2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    shape = layer2.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(layer2, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    FClayer = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(reshape, model.fc_weights), model.fc_biases))
    softmax_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(FClayer, model.Softmax_weights), model.Softmax_biases)
    return softmax_layer

def reshapedata(data_train,data_test,model):
   data_train = np.reshape(data_train,[-1,16,12,1])
   data_test  = np.reshape(data_test,[-1, 16,12,1])
return data_train,data_test

def batchdata(data,label, batchsize):
    # generate random number required to batch data
    order_num = random.sample(range(1, len(data)), batchsize)
    data_batch = []
    label_batch = []
    for i in range(len(order_num)):
        data_batch.append(data[order_num[i-1]])
        label_batch.append(label[order_num[i-1]])
    return data_batch, label_batch

sess = tf.Session()
data_train, data_test, label_train, label_test = load_data(Datainfo, ClassInfo, folder)
data_train, data_test, = reshapedata(data_train, data_test, model)
# input output placeholders
x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5, 16,12,1]) 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5, 8])
y  = mycnn(x)
# loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
# train step
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(STEPS):
    image_batch, label_batch = batchdata(data_train, label_train, model.BATCH_SIZE)

    c = sess.run( cost, feed_dict={x: image_batch, y_: label_batch})
    print('Epoch',i,'completed out of',STEPS,'loss:',c )
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={ x: image_batch, y_: label_batch})
```

my cost function

```
Epoch 495 completed out of 500 loss: 2.09191
Epoch 496 completed out of 500 loss: 2.1098`
Epoch 497 completed out of 500 loss: 2.05045
Epoch 498 completed out of 500 loss: 2.08442
Epoch 499 completed out of 500 loss: 2.09257
```

## update

I have added one more line in the network`FClayer = tf.nn.dropout(FClayer,0.8)`, and my cost function is showing some tend but not smooth. 
what did happened when I added that code piece ? Any suggestions to smooth the cost function [image]

Graph: x axis - number of iteration, y axis - cost

when I used dropout value as 0.6 accuracy on test samples is 63%, when dropout 0.8 and 1.0 accuracy on test samples - 80%, and 40% respectively.

Comment: What about the first epochs? Hard to tell if it doesn't learn or if it stopped learning. What about the accuracy on the training set (to see if it learns anything)? If accuracy on the training set doesn't improve, then there clearly is a problem. 

If training accuracy is fine, then it might be that you are not regularizing properly, where your model is *really* over-fitting. In fact, I don't see any regularization in your model.

Comment: Epoch 1 to 500, loss is almost similar. Accuracy os around 0.2 sometimes even on training set. I was concern about the training accuracy. Still i didnt test with the test samples.

Comment: axes updated for the figure

Comment: Non-smooth cost function is normal, since you are showing the cost function at every iteration (and possibly with a small batch size). Also, dropout sometimes makes the cost much larger for certain iterations, especially in smaller networks. Your network seems to be learning, so now it's a question of fine tuning it for optimal performance :).